# keras reinforcement learning - action with multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to set up a DQNAgent or a DDPGAgent in keras-rl, with a custom environment.
I need the model to give an output (action) of 48 numbers (basically an array). I tried to define the output as a spaces.box object like this:

```
self.action_space = spaces.Box(low=self.boundsLow, high=self.boundsHigh, shape=(48, ), dtype=np.int32)
```

I also tried a Multidiscrete action space.

The error is that in the step() function I only receive I value (number) from the neural network:
    ```
def step(self, action):
        print(action)

````
The neural network:
    ```
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape))
model.add(Dense(300))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(300))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(300))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(48))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())
````

How is it possible that I only receive one number as action?
Could anyone help?

Thank you!